# notify angular to update dom (changed with d3js)

Tags: angularjs, d3.js

I use angular and D3 to show a graph. I got graph data with angular and create it via D3js and append it to `#graph` element. For first time it work fine but when I change criteria and got new data, my graph wasn't updated. how can I notify angular to update dom. tank you.

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/degree',
    data: criteria,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
}).success(function (response) {  
    createGraph(response);
});
```

create graph with d3 and append it to #graph element

```
var createGraph = function(response){
....
    var svg = d3.select("#graph").append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h);
.....
}
```

html

```
    <div id="graph">
    </div>
```

Comment: refer this [http://jsfiddle.net/UBf9y/]

Comment: return 404, page not found

Comment: a similar question was asked beafore. plz read the answer to it. the above link is also provided there [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22052694/how-to-update-d3-js-bar-chart-with-new-data]

Comment: @farhad the problem is that every time you are calling the createGraph you are making new svg.

Comment: @Cyri I define svg outside of createGraph function, but my problem didn`t solve

Comment: I remove #graph and then create it again, thank you