# d3.js - updating stacked bar chart with new dataset

Tags: d3.js, charts

I’m starting with d3.js and built a simple stacked chart.

Now I want to be able to update the chart with new dataset on click.

I followed tutorials and especially the [Thinking with Joins](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/) article, the [General Update Pattern](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218) example and this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22052694/how-to-update-d3-js-bar-chart-with-new-data) but I didn’t manage to apply the **enter/update/exit** logic to my example.

As you can see in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8gp8x89c/), the updated axis are placed on top of the previous one and the chart doesn’t update with the new data.

```
var data1 = [
    {month: 'Jan', A: 20, B: 5, C: 10},
    {month: 'Feb', A: 30, B: 10, C: 20}
];

var data2 = [
    {month: 'Mar', A: 10, B: 55, C: 100},
    {month: 'Apr', A: 10, B: 70, C: 2}
];

var xData = ["A", "B", "C"];

var margin = {top: 20, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 50},
        width = 400 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .rangeRoundBands([0, width], 0.35);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .rangeRound([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left");

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


function draw(data) {
    var dataIntermediate = xData.map(function (c) {
        return data.map(function (d) {
            return {x: d.month, y: d[c]};
        });
    });

    var dataStackLayout = d3.layout.stack()(dataIntermediate);

    x.domain(dataStackLayout[0].map(function (d) {
        return d.x;
    }));

    y.domain([0,
        d3.max(dataStackLayout[dataStackLayout.length - 1],
                function (d) { return d.y0 + d.y;})
        ])
      .nice();

    var layer = svg.selectAll(".stack")
            .data(dataStackLayout);

            layer.exit().remove(); // has no effect

            layer.enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "stack")
            .style("fill", function (d, i) {
                return color(i);
            });

    var rect = layer.selectAll("rect")
            .data(function (d) {
                return d;
            });

            rect.exit().remove(); // has no effect

            rect.enter().append("rect")
                .attr("x", function (d) {
                    return x(d.x);
                })
                .attr("y", function (d) {
                    return y(d.y + d.y0);
                })
                .attr("height", function (d) {
                    return y(d.y0) - y(d.y + d.y0);
                })
                .attr("width", x.rangeBand());



    svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "axis")
            .call(yAxis);
}

function updateData() {
    draw(data2);
}

d3.select('#update')
    .on("click", updateData);

draw(data1);
```

Could you please explain where to insert the **exit** there and why?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the **enter/update/exit** logic;

When you first create your `svg`, the `enter` part takes the new nodes and appends them to the `svg`.

When you update your `svg`, the `select` part updates your data and styles. And the `exit` part removes the data as you know.

So according to this your pattern is almost correct but when you `select` your new data(update), you are not updating your styles.

Here's the part you need to change:

```
var rect = layer.selectAll("rect")
            .data(function (d) {
                return d;
            }).attr("x", function (d) {
                    return x(d.x);
                })
                .attr("y", function (d) {
                    return y(d.y + d.y0);
                })
                .attr("height", function (d) {
                    return y(d.y0) - y(d.y + d.y0);
                })
                .attr("width", x.rangeBand());
```

And here's the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8gp8x89c/2/

Note that the axis' are still present so you either remove and re-append them or apply the update pattern to them also. I leave that part to you.

Comment: many thanks, really helped! I just fixed the axis issue, added `rect.exit().remove();` and some transitions and looks fine now: [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tmfoq14q/4/)

Comment: @Surreal glad you figured it out :)