# Update Bar chart on new data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dynamic, charts, data-visualization

I'm working with d3 js (d3.v3.min.js) and want to update bar chart on new data dynamically after getting data from a query in JSON format.And here is my complete code

```
    var data = jsondata;
        // sample data

        //     var data = [{"year":"04-10-2018","value":"20"},
        //    {"year":"05-10-2018","value":"40"},
        //    {"year":"06-10-2018","value":"60"},
        //    {"year":"07-10-2018","value":"80"},
        //    {"year":"08-10-2018","value":"100"},
        //    {"year":"09-10-2018","value":"120"}];

         var margin = {top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 90, left: 50},
         width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
         height = 380 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d").parse;
        var formatTime = d3.time.format("%a");
        var formatxAxis = d3.format('.0f');

        var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .rangeRoundBands([0, width],.50);

        var y = d3.scale.linear()
            .range([height, 0]);

        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x)
            .orient("bottom")
            .tickFormat(formatTime);

        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(y)
            .tickFormat(formatxAxis)
            .orient("left")
            .ticks(5);

        var div = d3.select("#Graph").append("div") 
            .attr("class", "tooltip")               
            .style("opacity", 0);

        var svg = d3.select("#Graph").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

              data.forEach(function(d) {
                d.year = parseDate(d.year);
                d.value = +d.value;
            });

        x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.year; }));
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis)

        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .call(yAxis)
          .append("text")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
            .attr("y", 6)
            .attr("dy", ".71em")
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .text("Value");

function  updateChart(){

        var bar = svg.selectAll(".bar").data(data)

        // bar update after removing previous bar graph on div

        bar.exit().remove();

        bar.enter().append("rect")
            .attr("class", "bar x-axis")   
            .attr("width", x.rangeBand())  
            .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.year); })
            .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
            .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
        //    .on("click", function(d){show();})
            .style("fill",'#BDC6E7') 
           .on("mouseover", function(d) {      
                    div.transition()        
                        .duration(200)      
                        .style("opacity", .9);      
                    div .html(formatTime(d.year) + "<br/>"  + d.value)  
                        .style("left", (d3.event.pageX ) + "px")     
                        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");    
                    })                  
                .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
                    div.transition()        
                        .duration(500)      
                        .style("opacity", 0);   
                });
}
 updateChart();
```

As I have referred to this given problem link [UPDATE BAR CHART](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22052694/how-to-update-d3-js-bar-chart-with-new-data)  and tried their solution `bar.exit().remove();` to remove previous bar graph with a new one, but it doesn't work out because the graph is not updated with my new data.

When I try to inspect my graph changes activities in inspect element console then I see that it create two 'SVG' one with data another one doesn't consist any data.

[image: Creating two svg with new data]

So I didn't figure out what I am doing wrong so please anyone can help me in this??

Comment: It should be `var bar = svg.selectAll(".bar").data(data)`. You're missing a dot.

Comment: Voting to close as `typo`.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I have put the dot at the same place but still graph doesn't updated on new data

Comment: And how could we know? If you're looking for help debugging your code please post the correct version.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado please check updated question, by the way, I'm working with this version d3.v3.min.js

Comment: @GerardoFurtado any other thing, you need to know?

Comment: Yes, not for me, but for anyone trying to help you: there is nothing in this code updating the chart.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado As I have also mentioned in my question that I providing data dynamically from the SQL query in JSON format and I have referred to given link as a solution for updating my graph by using this 'bar.exit().remove();' . If is there any other solution please help me with that

Comment: @GerardoFurtado can you suggest me an article that relates to my problem?

Comment: @MikhailShabrikov  Can you help me in this?

Comment: @FernOfTheAndes Can you help me in this?

Comment: @WilfredoSánchezVega  Can you help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

After facing lots of problems while updating bar graph, I decided to clear SVG on every new data update because whenever I try to update my graph it creates another SVG on the same div instead of updating the same SVG.

So i have used this code `d3.select("#Graph").select("div").remove();` to clear the existing svg without creating another svg on new data update.

So here is my complete code

```
  var data = jsondata;   

 var margin = {top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 90, left: 50},
        width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 380 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    // Parse the date / time
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d").parse;
var formatTime = d3.time.format("%a");
var formatxAxis = d3.format(".2s");

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width],.50);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickFormat(formatTime)


var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .tickFormat(formatxAxis)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(5);

 d3.select("#Graph").select("div").remove();

var div = d3.select("#Graph").append("div") 
    .attr("class", "tooltip")               
    .style("opacity", 0);

    d3.select("#Graph").select("svg").remove();

var svg = d3.select("#Graph").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

 //   

      // Title
  svg.append("text")
    .text("Total Packs")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("class", "graph-title")
    .attr("y", -30)
    .attr("x", width / 2.0);

  svg.append("text")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("style", "font-size: 1.5 em")
    .attr("y", height + 50)
    .attr("x", width / 2.0);

   // svg.call(tip);


      data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.year = parseDate(d.year);
        d.value = +d.value;
    });  

x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.year; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis x-axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
            .selectAll("text")  
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("dx", "-.8em")
        .attr("dy", ".15em")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-65)");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis y-axis")
    .call(yAxis)


svg.selectAll("bar")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.year); })
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
    .style("fill",'#BDC6E7') 
   .on("mouseover", function(d) {      
            div.transition()        
                .duration(200)      
                .style("opacity", .9);      
            div .html(formatTime(d.year) + "<br/>"  + d.value)  
                .style("left", (d3.event.pageX ) + "px")     
                .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");    
            })                  
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
            div.transition()        
                .duration(500)      
                .style("opacity", 0);   
        });
```