# Choosing the data to display in d3

Tags: d3.js, visualization, data-visualization

How can I make a data visualization in d3 such that the data loaded changes when selecting an attribute? For example, if I have data that is a function of location, then I could select the location for which to display the data. 
The closest example I found [was](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/7030f35b72de721622b8) update, but then I cannot choose the data set to display.

Comment: have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14958825/dynamically-update-chart-data-in-d3

Comment: thank you for the link. This is not exactly what I would like to do though. I am looking for some kind of interactivity: Let's say that I have two locations, I would like the user to be able to select the data for a specific location he selects (in the link, they just click to update the graph and cannot select specific data to load)

Comment: I understand your request. Check the answer, may be you can slightly move to a d3 based library more suitable to your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain such level of interaction, you can focus on the library C3.js which is based on D3.

C3 provides a variety of APIs and callbacks to access the state of the chart. By using them, you can update the chart even if after it's rendered.

A sample of code could be as this one:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart',
    data: {
      columns: [
        ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
        ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
      ]
    }
});
```

By C3 definition both data1,data2 will be interactive elements you can deal with.

Documentation here: http://c3js.org/

Comment: you delete your new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28518454/visualizing-a-chart-using-c3 while I was writing down the solution. Issue was probably related to libraries loading