# Visualizing a chart using c3

Tags: html, visualization, data-visualization, c3

I am trying to reproduce some code to generate a [chart using c3](http://c3js.org/samples/simple_multiple.html). This script does not render anything though. Why? (the files listed in href are in the same folder)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!-- Load c3.css -->
  <link href="c3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  <!-- Load d3.js and c3.js -->
  <script src="d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="c3.min.js"></script>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>title </title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="chart"></div>
  <script>
  var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart',
    data: {
      columns: [
        ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
        ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
      ]
    }
});
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a working example so if chart is not loaded probably you are not referencing correctly to the libraries C3 and D3.

Check in the web console (usage in Chrome [here](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console)) of your browser if libraries are missing.

Check this steps:

- For C3 installation follow the guide: http://c3js.org/gettingstarted.html
- For D3 you can user the source remote connection:    http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js

Comment: I followed the instructions for installation, but the error is "ReferenceError: c3 is not defined". Yet, I am not referencing c3 anywhere

Comment: quick solution. copy the c3.min.js in the directory of the html file. If it works start reasoning how to structure your project in directories (example js/c3.min.js)

Answer (score 9):

For anyone else following this thread I would like to suggest you can use the following content delivery network (CDN) resources to load your D3.js, and C3.js libraries:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.min.css">  
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.min.js"></script>
```

I loaded your chart without a problem coding these resources into the `<head>` section of my document.